# multithreading with BFS, DFS searches

Tags: c++, multithreading

How does multithreading with like this? 
In multithreading with BFS, breadth first search, let's say you are running 10 threads and for the source there are only three adjacent rooms.  
How will multithreading work in this case?  Won't there only be three threads that can get through because if you put the "push" of the queue in the critical section, then the discovered set will be empty after only 3 threads, meaning only three threads will be able to get past that point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps checking out the Thread Pool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) pattern may help. Using the thread pool pattern, (depending on how you divvy up the work) it's certainly possible that lights workloads will cause some worker threads to remain idle.

Comment: I also recommend reading up on producer/consumer queues (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem), if you're not already familiar.

Comment: Can you provide more background on what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to implement multithreaded BFS/DFS search algorithms? Or do you want to do some parallel processing on vertices visited in BFS/ DFS order?

Comment: Parallel processing on the vertices visited, allowing me to more efficiently search.  The point is if I have a graph with thousands of vertices, then multithreading, that is having multiple objects search the graph concurrently would make it alot more efficient.

Comment: @Jake:  The performance gained by multithreading may be lost in the setup, coordination and takedown of the threads.  Perhaps sorting or developing an index (a container of pointers to vertices by category or key) will improve your performance.  Try to avoid threads, they bring up a lot of unwanted suprises.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Parallel Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html). It has parallel implementations for BFS and DFS.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You should assign the threads according to the number of adjacent vertices.

If a thread find all the adjacent vertices have been processed or processing by other threads, it should jump to synchronize operation and wait there.

You can use a shared variable to record how many threads are doing the visiting job. Compare the number to the size of adjacent table at the first line of a thread - if it is greater than the size, it means all the adjacent vertices has been hand to other threads in the system - the thread has nothing to do.